# Unity not loading project

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good morning. I'm using Unity 2019 at middle school in the computer lab. My problem is I'm trying to make a game, but it is stuck on Compiling Assembly Definition Files Scripts... and I've been waiting for 30 minutes, and it won't move. I'm using unity Student. I would like to know how to fix the problem that won't load the game I'm making. Thank you.

Comment: Try close it. Delete temp and library folder. If it doesn't work, post the editor log.

Comment: Start a new project and make a totally minimal scene (maybe "one cube" or such).  See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Joel, I would suggest using command prompt on Windows to
`taskkill /f /im unity.exe /t`
Or reinstalling the application